# Why is there no internet connection only for specific apps?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, mobile-data

My internet browsers, and most apps on my phone work fine, but specific ones: Sync pro, McDonalds, Pocket Casts, Audible, and Snapchat have weird semi-functionality.  I know I'm connected to wi-fi and mobile data because a majority of the apps work, however these listed do not.  I also can confirm that the services are not down because I have confirmed they work on a friend's device.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a difference with your device and the server's current time. Go to

```
Settings → System → Date & Time
```

Make sure the Automatic date & time setting is enabled.